# UICollectionView with Search Header and Pull To Refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

The idea is to have a search view into a UICollectionView and still be able to use pull to refresh with UIRefreshControl. 
The search and the UIRefreshControl will not be visible until the user scroll down the UICollectionView.

```
------------------
| Pull To Refresh |
------------------
|      Search     |
------------------    <--- Above of this line the content is hidden
|    A   |   B    |
------------------
|    C   |   D    |
------------------
|     Footer      |
------------------
```

I have tried implement the SearchView into an section header of the UICollectionView, but in this way I can not use reloadData while a cell of the collection view is the first responder.

A good solution should make possible to:

- Update the CollectionView datasource while the user type into the search box
- Don't mess the animation of the UIRefreshControl

Comment: did you ever make any progress on this?

Answer (score -3):

Use a scrollView instead of dealing with CollectionView. For the pull to refresh functionality you can use an open source as https://github.com/kenzan8000/PullRefreshView.

Comment: Why not just `UIRefreshControl`?

Comment: I'm only interested in a solution involving an UICollectionView.